# Yii2 Cookies not being removed

Tags: cookies, yii2

So I'm struggling to undertstand the concept of how cookies are managed in Yii2. I've seen some resources say to set cookies via:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
    'name' => 'some_cookie_name',
    'value' => 'some cookie value',
    'domain' => ( YII_ENV_DEV )? '.dev.example.co.uk' : '',
    'expire' => time() + (60*60*24*30) // Expire in 30 days time
]));
```

That works fine, but when it comes to removing a cookie using:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('some_cookie_name');
```

It doesn't work. The cookie remains in the browser.

To confirm, there is a redirect after the removal of the cookie.

Resource I'm looking at is: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies

Answer (score 2):

please try this

Creating a cookie

```
 $cookie = new Cookie( [
                        'name'   => 'some_cookie_name',
                        'value'  => some cookie value,
                        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
                    ] );
   \Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add( $cookie );
```

Removing a cookie

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
unset($cookies['some_cookie_name']);
or
$cookies->remove( 'some_cookie_name' );
```

Comment: improve this answer please. Why would someone click that link?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for remove cookie:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove(new Cookie([
    'name' => 'some_cookie_name',
    'domain' => ( YII_ENV_DEV )? '.dev.example.co.uk' : '',
]));
```

As [reference link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-cookiecollection.html#remove%28%29-detail).

`remove()` method can give `yii\web\Cookie | string`.

If you don't define `domain` when set cookie. default use of current domain name(without `.` in prefix). and so when you want to delete it. just you can use this:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('some_cookie_name');
```

But if you define `domain` when set cookie, so you should define it in remove method by pass a object instead of a string, be like this:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove(new Cookie([
    'name' => 'some_cookie_name',
    'domain' => 'your-domain.com',
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works best:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$cookies->remove('username');
unset($cookies['username']);
```

Referenced from 
Cookies handling in YII framework2.o found in the following link
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/cookies-handling-in-yii-framework2-0/

Answer (score 0):

this work for me , if you want to remove cookies from subdomain you need to specify that domain this should remove that cookie

```
    unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
    setcookie('cookie_name', null, -1, '/','your_domain.com');
```